# Insertion Function help alphabetical Linked List in C

Tags: c, linked-list, insertion, alphabetical-sort

I need some help with a linked list exercise in C.
I'm having trouble inserting each  word alphabetically into the list.
the listInsert function is the only thing that doesn't work. I tried to implement some code there but it's broken, feel free to remove it.

```
//sorting strings using linked list.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define SUCCESS 0
#define FAIL    1

char *phonetic[] = { "alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta", "echo", "foxtrot",
                     "golf", "hotel", "india", "juliet", "kilo", "lima", "mike",
                     "november", "oscar", "papa", "quebec", "romeo", "sierra",
                     "tango", "uniform", "victor", "whisky", "xray", "yankee", 
                     "zulu" };

unsigned char indexes[] = { 1, 14, 17, 3, 22, 0, 5, 18, 24, 11, 4, 6, 13, 21,
                            2, 12, 25, 19, 10, 16, 7, 9, 23, 15, 20, 8 };                       

// represents an entry in the linked-list
struct listEntry
{
  char *data_p;               // pointer to the entry's string
  struct listEntry *prev_p;   // pointer to previous entry in the linked-list  
  struct listEntry *next_p;   // pointer to next entry in the linked-list
};

// represents the linked-list
struct list
{
  int entryCount;             // number of entries present in the linked-list
  struct listEntry *head_p;   // pointer to the first entry in the list  
  struct listEntry *tail_p;   // pointer to the last entry in the list
};

// Dynamically allocate & initialise an empty linked list
int listCreate(struct list** list_p2)
{
  // allocate struct list from heap 
  *list_p2 = (struct list*) malloc(sizeof(**list_p2));

  if (*list_p2 != NULL)
  {
    // zero-initialize the list structure 
    memset(*list_p2, 0, sizeof(**list_p2));
    return SUCCESS;    
  }

  return FAIL;
}

// Free all entries in the linked-list and the list structure
int listDestroy(struct list *list_p)
{
  if (list_p != NULL)
  {
    struct listEntry *entry_p = list_p->head_p;

    while (entry_p != NULL)
    {
      struct listEntry *next_p = entry_p->next_p;
      // free the current entry
      free(entry_p);
      // move to the next entry
      entry_p = next_p;
    }

    // free list structure
    free(list_p);
  }

  return FAIL;
}

// Traverse the linked-list from head to tail printing out
// the string data from each list entry
int listPrintForward(struct list *list_p)
{ 
  if (list_p)
  {    
    struct listEntry *entry_p = list_p->head_p;
    int count = 0;

    printf("FORWARD: %d entries\n", list_p->entryCount);
    while (entry_p != NULL)
    {
      if ((count > 0) && (count % 5 == 0))
      {
        printf("%s\n", entry_p->data_p);
      }
      else
      {      
        printf("%s ", entry_p->data_p);
      }

      if (entry_p == list_p->tail_p)
        printf("\n");

      entry_p = entry_p->next_p;
      fflush(stdout);
      count++;         
    }

    return SUCCESS;
  }

  return FAIL;
}

// Traverse the linked-list from tail to head printing out
// the string data from each list entry
int listPrintReverse(struct list *list_p)
{ 
  if (list_p)
  {    
    struct listEntry *entry_p = list_p->tail_p;
    int count = 0;

    printf("REVERSE: %d entries\n", list_p->entryCount);   
    while (entry_p != NULL)
    {
      if ((count > 0) && (count % 5 == 0))
      {
        printf("%s\n", entry_p->data_p);
      }
      else
      {      
        printf("%s ", entry_p->data_p);
      }

      if (entry_p == list_p->head_p)
        printf("\n");

      entry_p = entry_p->prev_p;
      fflush(stdout);
      count++;         
    }

    return SUCCESS;
  }

  return FAIL;
}

// Insert the given string into the linked-list such that the
// entries in the linked-list are in alphabetical order
int listInsert(struct list *list_p, char *string_p)
{/*BROKEN CODE
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(indexes); i++)
    {
        list_p = malloc(sizeof(indexes));
        if (string_p[i] = ' ')
            list_p -> data = 0;
        else
            list_p ->entryCount;
    }
    */
    return FAIL;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ////Creating list and initializing to NULL.
  struct list *list_p = NULL;
  (void) argc;
  (void) argv;
   ////Calls code as list has been created. 
  if (listCreate(&list_p) == SUCCESS)
  {
    unsigned int count;

    // insert every word in the phonetic alphabet into the
    // linked-list.
    printf("INSERT:\n");
    for (count = 0; count < sizeof(indexes); count++)
    {
      if ((count > 0) && (count % 5 == 0))
      {
        printf("%s\n", phonetic[indexes[count]]);
      }
      else
      {
        printf("%s ", phonetic[indexes[count]]);
      }
      listInsert(list_p, phonetic[indexes[count]]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // print out the list in alphabetical order
    listPrintForward(list_p);
    // print out the list in reverse alphabetical order
    listPrintReverse(list_p); 

    // Destroy the linked list and free all associated memory
    listDestroy(list_p);               
  }

  return SUCCESS;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thankyou!

Comment: Can you write code which inserts to the beginning? Can you write code which inserts to the end? Can you write code which inserts somewhere in the middle, between two adjacent nodes? Can you write code to figure out where to insert? If the answers are yes, combine these pieces of code to the final solution.

Comment: Hi pts, i can't sorry. This is all the code i have, it's a code exercise. All i need to do is to insert a given string into the linked-list such that entries in the linked-list are in alphabetical order.

Comment: I'm sure that the textbook your professor has recommended to you contains enough information for you to write codes above. If not, I recommend reading the following book: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language

Comment: Ok i'll give it a look now, will report back.

Comment: I cant find anything in The C Programmming Language book to help me with this example. Any help please?

Comment: Does this help? http://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists I'm sure that based on this you can write code to insert to the beginning of the list. If not, search for *double-linked list tutorial* on the web.

Comment: Ok cheers i'll give it a look now. For reference , would you know how to solve this?

Comment: still doesnt help. :(

Comment: To write a insert function, you will need to know how a linked list works... To compare two strings according to the alphabetical order, you may combine `strncmp()`, `strlen()` from string.h and `tolower()` from ctype.h. First : convert to lower (a for loop) then get `min(strlen(s1),strlen(s2))`. Then compute `strncmp(s1,s2,min)`. If 0, compute `strcmp(s1,s2)`. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/